# Format a csv using regex

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a csv file with 5 numbers in each line.

```
a line in csv:- 10003478,12228,7711479,15013889,3070120,5834262
```

I need to convert this string into something like this

```
expected:- 10003478,2/28/12228,4/79/7711479,8/89/15013889,1/20/3070120,2/62/5834262
```

In the expected output, the numbers around '/' are the last three digits of each number.

Eg: 12228 - last three digits are 228 which are separated like that and made into 2/28/12228

Comment: Parse it (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), transform it, write it back to file.

Comment: Your not asking us to help you solve the problem? :) why is the first number special?

Comment: @MinhKieu, no I'm not. It's just that I'm unable to understand where to start from. Actually there are a few more checks to be done along with above operations. A pointer where to start from would help me a lot.
First number is a special code which don't need transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replaceAll` method and save it into a new String:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Read file
        Path filePath = Paths.get("file.txt");
        byte[] arr = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
        String content = new String(arr, Charset.defaultCharset());

        // Replace
        String newContent = new String(
                content.replaceAll(",([0-9]+)([0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})", ",$2/$3/$1$2$3"));

        System.out.println(newContent);
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
10003478,2/28/12228,4/79/7711479,8/89/15013889,1/20/3070120,2/62/5834262
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a pattern like this:

```
,((\d+)(\d)(\d{2}))
```

and do a `replaceAll` with:

```
,$3/$4/$1
```

Example  in javascript:

```js
console.log("10003478,12228,7711479,15013889,3070120,5834262".replace(/,((\d+)(\d)(\d{2}))/g, ",$3/$4/$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you should use regex. Instead you can just read the file and convert the strings and write back to file. Below is an example how it could look like using OpenCsv

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class JavaApplication22 {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
       String path = "C:\\Users\\uzochi\\desktop\\numbers.csv";
       CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path));
       List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();

       for(String[] s : myEntries){
           for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
              String last3 = s[i].substring(s[i].length()-3,s[i].length()); 
              last3 = last3.charAt(0)+"/"+last3.substring(1)+"/";
              s[i] = last3+s[i];               
           }
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
       }

       CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path), ','); 
       for(String[] s : myEntries){       
          writer.writeNext(s);
       }
   writer.close();
   }    
 }
```

about [openCsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)